# Python/Pandas if statement and index

Tags: python, function, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this problem but I cannot seem to find it.

I am trying to check if an age from a list is in the age column of my dataframe. However, it is only comparing to the index and not the column.

Here is a simplified piece of code from my program:

```
def findages(data,ages):
    for age in ages:
        if age in data['age']:
            print('yes')
        else:
            print('no')
```

I have also tried this:

```
def findages(data,ages):
    for age in ages:
        if age in data.loc[data['age']]:
            print('yes')
        else:
            print('no')
```

the dataframe looks like this

```
                 age     x     Lambda             L
0       1.258930e+05  0.01       91.0  5.349000e+25
1       1.258930e+05  0.01       94.0  1.188800e+26
2       1.258930e+05  0.01       96.0  1.962700e+26
3       1.258930e+05  0.01       98.0  3.169400e+26   
4       1.258930e+05  0.01      100.0  5.010800e+26
```

and the list like this:

```
ages = ([125893.0, 4e7,5e9])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide an example input?

Comment: just updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## DataFrame column access return a Series

In your code, `data['age']` is returning a series of columns `age`. In this case the `in` operator will compare against the index.  To compare against the values in the series use the `.values` attribute to get an array of the series values.

### By example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'age':[33, 34], 'pet':['Dog', 'Cat']}, index=['Bob', 'Mary'])

ages = [5, 33, 67]

def findages(data, ages):
    for age in ages:
        if age in data['age'].values:
            print('yes')
        else:
            print('no')

findages(df, ages)
```

---

```
no
yes
no
```

Comment: No worries, takes some experience to get use to the interfaces and capabilities of the library.  Keep at it,  it is a very useful tool!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
np.where(data['age'].isin(ages),'yes','no')
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'age':[10,20,30]})
ages = [10,30]
print (data)
   age
0   10
1   20
2   30

data['new'] = np.where(data['age'].isin(ages),'yes','no')
print (data)
   age  new
0   10  yes
1   20   no
2   30  yes
```

EDIT by sample:

```
print (data)
        age     x  Lambda             L
0  125893.0  0.01    91.0  5.349000e+25
1  125893.0  0.01    94.0  1.188800e+26
2  125893.0  0.01    96.0  1.962700e+26
3  125893.0  0.01    98.0  3.169400e+26
4  125893.0  0.01   100.0  5.010800e+26

ages = ([125893.0, 4e7,5e9])
print (np.where(data['age'].isin(ages),'yes','no'))
['yes' 'yes' 'yes' 'yes' 'yes']
```